# How manage kafka topics in messaging chatroom

Tags: spring-kafka

i'm about to create a chatroom,  for  each two users like to exchange messages i like to create a Kafka  producer and Kafka Listener with a specific Topic to to them

Answer (score 0):

You are describing Topic per entity here. You could do that, but you shouldn't. Each topic will be a directory on the drive, and some open file handles. You would run out of open file handles if you are getting a lot of rooms.

You could create a "Chatrooms" topic with a number of partitions and have your chatrooms have unique id's. A listener would skip all messages not meant for that particular chatroom.

Comment: u suggest that i create a single topic that consume all messages  and then send each messages to the id room ??

Comment: Don't send each message to each room. With 1 topic you could do it quite simple, with a number of partitions you see fit, for replication. The key of the message should be chatroom id or something. Kafka makes sure all messages with a certain key will always be put in the same partition (at least until you rebalance your topics)

Comment: If you don't want to mix messages from chatrooms in the same sequence, I wouldn't recommend Kafka, probably eventstore would be better or any other storage which get identify streams by id

Comment: i have created a topic creator (Using Admin client) to create each room, the producer is the same for all rooms, but i can't configure  @KafkaListener(topics {,,,}) to listen to all topics automatic  when a new room has been created